# Why I can't change a bool twice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I actually have two questions. First of all, I have simple code

```
public float changeTime;
public float changeTimeStart;
public bool reversed;
public float nope;

void Update(){
change ();
}
void start(){
changeTime = Time.time + changeTimeStart;
reversed = false;
}
void change(){
        if (changeTime <= Time.time && reversed == false) {
        reversed = true;
        changeTime = Time.time + changeTime;
    }
    if (changeTime <= Time.time && reversed == true) {
        reversed = false;
        nope = 20;
    }
}
```

Basicly in the beginning reversed is set to false.

[image]

After 3 secs first if statement happens and it sets reversed to true. [image]
 
And after 3 more seconds second if statement happens and it sets the nope value to 20 but it doesn't set reversed value to false.

[image]

I can't understand why. Does the first if statement also works as soon as second statement set reversed to false? I basically want it to change every x second from false to true but I couldn't grasp the logic.

My second question is why it is 6.012766 not just 6?

[image]

Is this the time to reload the frame? Doesn't this make a problem if this cycle continues?

Comment: I think you're going to need to add a [mcve] because as it stands, I don't think things are happening as you say they are. If the `nope = 20;` line is running, then the line above it ran as well. Do you have something that's potentially re-overwriting `reversed`?

Comment: Well there are a lot of things in this script but I'll try to paste here the codes related to this problem. Well I edited the code and added everything in this script related to that function.

Comment: Is that all your script? there are not other references to reversed anywhere else?

Comment: yeah I only set it false in start and changed it in that function but I have no idea why I can't set it to false again in the function

Comment: if you want to see the whole script it is here https://anotepad.com/note/read/f7ajj7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply extend change time for *x* seconds each time when current time exceeds change time:

```
void change(){
    float changeRate = 3F; // x or changeTimeStart in your case

    if (Time.time < changeTime)
       return;

    reversed = !reversed;
    nope = 20; 
    changeTime = Time.time + changeRate; // or changeTime += changeRate
}
```

Your problem is doubling change time in the first case - instead of extending it by changeRate you are adding changeTime (which is a little less than the current time) with the current time. So changes will happen approx at 3, 6, 12, 24, 48 etc seconds.

And second problem is that you are not modifying changeTime in the second case. So after you change `reversed` to `false` on the next frame first condition hits (`changeTime <= Time.time` is still true) and changes `reversed` back to `true`.

Comment: My code should work like this: changeTime is set to 3. after 3 seconds first if statement will work. reversed will be set to true and changeTime will be itself+time passed. which is 3+3=6. And then after 3 more secs second if statement will work. reversed will be set to false again. and nope will be set to 20. Everything okay except reversed won't set to false again. I can't understand this. I am doubling changeTime because I want the second statement to happen after 3 seconds after first one. I can't understand why doubling is my problem

Comment: @Alex I have added example of change time to explain doubling problem. Also, you can read why `reversed` is immediately changes back to `true`. Note that `time` is a double (not precise) time in seconds of frame beginning. Even if you would have 1 fps this time would not be accurate

Comment: Now I see the problem. I thought I can't change the value to false. Actually I can but after the next frame it just changes to true again and I can't even realize that. Thank you a lot

Comment: Could you please also inform me if you know the answer? Why it is 6.012766 not just 6?